# Chromecast sample app CastHelloText-android not showing on Menubar

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

It's been two days since I've been trying to get the CastHelloText (https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) app to actually cast something to Chromecast with no success. I have followed the instructions on the README.md file. When I fire the app, the "Play on..." menu item does not get created.

I guess that the menu item depends upon something to get displayed, but this hook must be missing.

The app's code is unchanged from the GitHub but I'll paste the most relevant snippets here.

Creating the menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    return true;
}
```

The menu itself:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

I must say that I'm using Android Studio for the first time, and I had a few problems setting the dependencies, but now my code is compilling and running on the device. I have added the appcompat-v7, mediarouter-v7 and play-services libraries to my project.

Also, on another experiment I was able to include a MediaRouteButton on the MainActivity view, and tried to attach the same MediaRouteSelector to it. The button gets displayed on the app, but does not work.

Also I have tried creating a receiver app of my own and use it, to no success either.

Finally, I have found a closed bug reporting the same behaviour, and also posted some screenshots: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/issues/5

Comment: Note that your two code snippets are the same. Beyond that, is your Chromecast powered on and actively showing on a TV or monitor?

Comment: Yes, it is! YouTube, Netflix and Play Movies are able to cast to it.